# MSSQL query delete evrything else but me

Tags: sql-server

I am needing help for building a specific query.

**Scenario**

I have a table A with pol_id (auto_incremente), someOtherID and someValue

The content of the table could look something like this:

```
pol_id, someOtherID, someValue
--------------------------------
1       5005         I Like cheeseburger
2       5005         I Like Bananas 
3       6000         In Toronto
4       6018         Open the door
5       6018         Really
6       6018         French Fries
```

There is a 3rd party software, which gathers data from that table. I don't have any influence to manipulate the sql statements the software uses, because I don't have access to it's source code.

The 3rd party software selects everything with 'someOtherID' is e.g. 6018, so it displays 3 results. The problem is, I only want the last result (with the highest pol_id) to be displayed. So I guess i'll do a cronjob or something which do the following:

select each unique someOtherIDs descending,
delete everything from that table with someOtherID equals selected one and a different pol_id

something like this:

```
pseudocode:

select distinct someOtherID, pol_id from A order by pol_id DESC --to get the highest one

for each someOtherID as selectedLine:

delete from A where someOtherID = selectedLine.someOtherID AND pol_id != selectedLine.pol_id
```

i'd like to run this statement every few seconds or place it on a trigger or something so that table A is always clean

**edit**
i went for the trigger solution from damien, thank you all for your respond.

Comment: Thank you for your responds, but tell me, why the down votes? i tried to explain everything exactly as I could. was it my bad spelling or my lack of knowledge of the english language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy with a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_TableA_I
on TableA
after insert
as
    set nocount on

    delete from a
    from
        TableA a
            inner join
        (select someOtherID,MAX(pol_id) as maxPol from inserted
         group by someOtherID) b
            on
               a.someOtherID = b.SomeOtherID and
               a.pol_id < maxPol
```

Which should work even if there's a multi-row insert containing two or more rows with the same `someOtherID`

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH a as
(
 SELECT row_number() over (partition by someOtherID order by pol_id desc) rn 
 FROM tableA
)
DELETE FROM a where rn > 1
```

Comment: i'll give this also a try if the trigger solution from damien won't work, thank you for your respond

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from t where 
exists (select 1 from t t1 
                  where t1.someOtherID=t.someOtherID
                  and   t1.pol_id>t.pol_id)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e1c7/1)

Comment: ill give this a try if the trigger solution from damien won't work, thank you for your respond

Answer (score 0):

You could try this
Delete A where someOtherID = '6018' and pol_id not in (
Select Max(Pol_id) from A where someOtherID = '6018');

Comment: thank you, but i guess i'll heading for the trigger solution. that way the table keeps it clean itself. thank you for your respond